# How do I import a CSV file into SQL PLUS?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, import, bulkinsert

I have created a database and have my tables, but I need to implement some data into it, to avoid writing out 5000+ entries I have decided to download **'dummy data (fake)'** for names, numbers, address, etc.

I have tried using **"BULK INSERT"** but **SQL** does not accept this, is there any other way of implementing the fake data?

Comment: What format is the fake data in? You might be able to use SQL*Loader, or an external table, or SQL Developer's import data functionality.

Comment: you're in luck, or soon will be. Our new SQL*Plus, SQLcl, will have an import command that will read in a CSV and move the data into a table, assuming the columns match up sequentially. Stay tuned for more info. It's in beta now on our SQL Developer OTN page.

Comment: the fake data is in a CSV format @AlexPoole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Plus can only interpret commands given by console or read from script. You have to create script with set of insert commands and run it from SQL Plus. I used this approach more times, it's not as difficult.

Write your script like this:

```
declare
  procedure change_data(your_data_in_parameters) is
  begin
     set_of_our_commands_to_handle_one_record;
  end;
begin
    change_data(your_data_from_CSV_row1);
    change_data(your_data_from_CSV_row2);
    ...
    commit;
end;
```

Open your CSV in some spreadsheet editor and add new formula column which collects `change_data` rows.